# Java RegEx чтобы заменить все <b></b> на "" внутри тега <pre>

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текст:

```html
<html>
...
<pre>
<b>println("Hello!. I need your help");</b>
<b>println("because Iam newbie");</b>
</pre>
<pre>
<b>println("I know");</b>
<b>println("you can help me");</b>
</pre>
<b>bold stay here</b>
....
</html>
```

Я хочу заменить в нем `<b>` и `</b>` на `""` , но только те, которые находятся внутри тега `<pre>`

```html
<html>
....
<pre>
println("Hello!. I need your help");
println("because Iam newbie");
</pre>
<pre>
println("I know");
println("you can help me");
</pre>
<b>bold stay here</b>
....
</html>
```

Как это сделать при помощи `replaceAll();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить с помощью Matcher и Pattern

```
private static String input ="<html>\n" + 
            "...\n" + 
            "<pre>\n" + 
            "<b>println(\"Hello!. I need your help\");</b>\n" + 
            "<b>println(\"because Iam newbie\");</b>\n" + 
            "</pre>\n" + 
            "<pre>\n" + 
            "<b>println(\"I know\");</b>\n" + 
            "<b>println(\"you can help me\");</b>\n" + 
            "</pre>\n" + 
            "<b>bold stay here</b>\n" + 
            "....\n" + 
            "</html>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(<pre>\n(<b>.*<\/b>\n){1,}<\/pre>)");
        Matcher m = pt.matcher(input);
        if(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Найдена группа:\n "+m.group());

            System.out.println("\nМеняем тег <b>:\n "+m.group().replace("<b>","").replace("</b>", ""));
        }

            }
```

Результат

```
Найдена группа:
 <pre>
<b>println("Hello!. I need your help");</b>
<b>println("because Iam newbie");</b>
</pre>

Меняем тег <b>:
 <pre>
println("Hello!. I need your help");
println("because Iam newbie");
</pre>
```